# LINQ to DataSet Query Help

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, dataset

I'm really new to LINQ so I'm hoping someone can help me. I've got a database which I need to run a large query from but it's a really old ODBC driver and takes a long time to respond (30+min for even a simple query). It only takes about 2-3min to dump all the data into a dataset however so I figured this was best and then I could run a LINQ to Dataset query. I can't seem to get the query to work and I'm a little confused. I put all the data into an SQL Express database to test the LINQ to SQL query to make sure I was going down the right path. I don't have this option where the application is going to be run as the environment will always be different.

SQL:

```
SELECT Invoice_detail.Code, Invoice_detail.Description, Product_master.Comment AS Packing, Invoice_detail.QtyInv AS INV, Invoice_detail.QtyBackOrder AS BO, Alternate_product_codes.MasterBarCode AS BarCode, Invoice_detail.PriceAmt AS Price, Invoice_detail.DiscPerc AS Disc, ROUND(Invoice_detail.TaxableAmt/Invoice_detail.QtyInv,2) AS Nett FROM ((Invoice_detail INNER JOIN Product_master ON Invoice_detail.Code = Product_master.Code) INNER JOIN Invoice_header ON Invoice_detail.InternalDocNum = Invoice_header.InternalDocNum AND Invoice_detail.DocType = Invoice_header.DocType) LEFT JOIN Alternate_product_codes ON Invoice_detail.Code = Alternate_product_codes.Code WHERE Invoice_header.DocNum = '{0}' AND Invoice_header.DocType = 1 AND Invoice_detail.LineType = 1 AND Invoice_detail.QtyInv > 0
```

LINQ to SQL:

```
from detail in INVOICE_DETAILs
join prodmast in PRODUCT_MASTERs on detail.Code equals prodmast.Code
join header in INVOICE_HEADERs on new { detail.InternalDocNum, detail.DocType } equals new { header.InternalDocNum, header.DocType}
join prodcodes in ALTERNATE_PRODUCT_CODES on detail.Code equals prodcodes.Code into alt_invd
from prodcodes in alt_invd.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  header.DocType == 1 &&
  detail.LineType == 1 &&
  detail.QtyInv > 0 &&
  header.Date > DateTime.Parse("17/07/2011").Date &&
  header.DocNum.Trim() == "119674"
select new {
  detail.Code,
  detail.Description,
  Packing = prodmast.Comment,
  INV = detail.QtyInv,
  BO = detail.QtyBackOrder,
  Barcode = prodcodes.MasterBarCode, 
  Price = detail.PriceAmt, 
  Disc = detail.DiscPerc,
  Nett = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(detail.TaxableAmt/detail.QtyInv),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
}
```

LINQ to Dataset:

```
var query = from detail in ds.Tables["Invoice_detail"].AsEnumerable()
join prodmast in ds.Tables["Product_master"].AsEnumerable() on detail["Code"] equals prodmast["Code"]
join header in ds.Tables["Invoice_header"].AsEnumerable() on new { docnum = detail["InternalDocNum"], doctype = detail["DocType"] } equals new { docnum = header["InternalDocNum"], doctype = header["DocType"] }
join prodcodes in ds.Tables["Alternate_product_codes"].AsEnumerable() on detail["Code"] equals prodcodes["Code"] into alt_invd
from prodcodes in alt_invd.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  (int)header["DocType"] == 1 &&
  (int)detail["LineType"] == 1 &&
  (int)detail["QtyInv"] > 0 &&
  //header.Field<DateTime>("Date") > DateTime.Parse("17/07/2011").Date &&
  header.Field<DateTime>("Date") > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7) &&
  header.Field<string>("DocNum").Trim() == "119674"
select new
{
    Code = detail["Code"],
    Description = detail["Description"],
    Packing = prodmast["Comment"],
    INV = detail["QtyInv"],
    BO = detail["QtyBackOrder"],
    Barcode = prodcodes["MasterBarCode"],
    Price = detail["PriceAmt"],
    Disc = detail["DiscPerc"],
    Nett = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((double)detail["TaxableAmt"] / (int)detail["QtyInv"]), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
};
```

I need to run the LINQ to DataSet query and then put the results into a DataTable so that I can export to CSV. The query will return many rows so I can see the CopyToDataTable method however that doesn't seem to work unless it is a typed dataset. I'm using the ODBC data adapter fill method so not specifically setting the data types on the Datatables I'm filling. The reason for this is that there is a lot of columns in those tables and setting them all up would be time consuming.

Is LINQ the best option? Am I close? Do I have to set the DataTables up for all the columns and data types? The only other way I can think of is to dump the data into an access database every time and query from there. I'm more curious to get LINQ to work though as I think it's going to be more beneficial for me going forward.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Thanks.

Pete.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using POCO objects instead of a DataSet.

[Blogs @ MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/06/21/dataset-versus-plain-objects.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the Linq To Dataset query retrieves the correct information, but you are not able to export the information to csv.

If this is just one csv file you need creating using just the nine fields in your example, you may be able to use a csv library (for example [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)) to export the information.

To give you an example of the extra work involved, you need to define a class eg

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")] 
public class Info
{ 
    [FieldQuoted()] 
    public string Code ;
    [FieldQuoted()] 
    public string Description ;
    [FieldQuoted()] 
    public string Packing ; 
    public decimal INV ;
    public decimal BO ;
    [FieldQuoted()] 
    public string Barcode ;
    public decimal Price ; 
    public decimal Disc ;
    public decimal Nett ;

}
```

(Note, I'm guessing some of the field types)

You then change your query to use Info , ie

```
select new Info {
    Code = detail["Code"],
 ...
```

and finally

```
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Info)); 
    engine.WriteFile(".\\outputfile.csv", query);
```

and you are done.